# ToProvider With Constructor Arguments in Ninject Doesn't Bind Correct Constructor

Tags: .net, vb.net, inversion-of-control, ninject

I have this simple binding:

```
Bind(Of ISessionFactory).ToProvider(Of SessionProvider) _
             .InSingletonScope() _
             .WithConstructorArguments("connectionString ", "test")
```

With this provider:

```
Public Class SessionProvider
    Inherits Provider(Of ISessionFactory)

    Private ReadOnly ConnectionString As String

    Public Sub New(connectionString as String)
        Me.ConnectionString = connectionString
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function CreateInstance(context As IContext) As ISessionFactory
        Return New SessionFactory(connectionName)
    End Function
End Class
```

But when it goes to resolve the factory is **always** calls the default constructor with no arguments. I've tried adding the `Inject` attribute to the constructor, I've even tried adding a default constructor that is private. Nothing works.

My only solution so far is to create another class that is resolved automatically. It looks like this:

My Intermediate factory with constructor arguments:

```
Public Class MySessionFactory
    Private ReadOnly ConnectionName As String

    Private Factory As ISessionFactory

    Public Sub New(ByVal connectionName As String)
        Me.ConnectionName = connectionName
    End Sub


    Public Function GetFactory() As ISessionFactory
        Return new SessionFactory(ConnectionName)
    End Function
End Class
```

The provider:

```
Public Class SessionProvider
    Inherits Provider(Of ISessionFactory)

    Private ReadOnly FactoryProvider As SessionFactory

    Public Sub New(factory As MySessionFactory)
        Me.FactoryProvider = factory
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function CreateInstance(context As IContext) As ISessionFactory
        Return FactoryProvider.GetFactory()
    End Function
End Class
```

My binding that takes constructor args:

```
Bind(Of SessionFactory).ToSelf().WithConstructorArgument("connectionName", "TEST")
Bind(Of ISessionFactory).ToProvider(Of SessionProvider).InSingletonScope()
```

This intermediate class will bind with constructor arguments but isn't really a solution because it doesn't decouple anything much more. I might as well hard code the connection name into the provider if I do it this way...which is obviously no good...

So I would like to avoid this intermediate class and would like my provider to accept constructor arguments?

Comment: i've added an issue report to the ninject github tracker: https://github.com/ninject/ninject/issues/136

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried:

```
Bind(Of ISessionFactory).ToProvider(Of SessionProvider) _
         .InSingletonScope()

Bind(Of SessionProvider).ToSelf() _
         .WithConstructorArguments("connectionString ", "test")
```

as a workaround?

Also note that the `.InSingletonScope()` affects the `ISessionFactory`, not the `SessionProvider`.
You are telling ninject to not instanciate more than one `ISessionFactory`. Of course, not more than one `SessionProvider` will be instanciated - there's no need to create more of them after having creating the first and only `ISessionFactory` instance.

But if you'd want to only create one `SessionProvider` but multiple `ISessionFactory` you'd also have to create a binding for the `SessionProvider` and set that to `.InSingletonScope()` - much as i showed above with the `.WithConstructorArguments(...)`.

Comment: That makes sense now that you say it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your binding definition

```
Bind(Of ISessionFactory).ToProvider(Of SessionProvider) _
         .InSingletonScope() _
         .WithConstructorArguments("connectionString ", "test")
```

binds the `ISessionFactory` to a provider of type `SessionProvider`. The constructor argument is only used for resolving requests for the type `ISessionFactory`, not for resolving requests for `SessionProvider`. In your example, Ninject initially creates a request for `SessionProvider`. Hence, you have to define an additional binding for `SessionProvider` as described in the previous post.

When requesting a `ISessionFactory`, the constructor argument is passed into the request. Check the parameters of the context argument in the `CreateInstance` override (c# code, I am not fluent in VB.NET)

```
    protected override Service CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        string t = (string)context.Parameters.Cast<IConstructorArgument>().First().GetValue(context, context.Request.Target);
        return new Service(t);
    }
```